# Use flyway on JSE project

Tags: flyway

I need to use flywaydb in my JSE project, so it's possible to configure the flaway to get the sql files from package inside my .jar file??

if it's possible how i do this?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official **[first steps tutorial](http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/api.html)** for the Flyway API and you should be up and running in no time.